# Blast Radius Spritekit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, blast

Im trying to create an explosion that when a certain object is hit, objects in the nearby radius also get destroyed. For example, in a brick breaker game, the ball hits a brick and then the brick explodes but also explodes 2 bricks in every direction as well. How can this be accomplished? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but the spritekit way is to create a blast sprite node. You can animate it as needed with SKAction and use the same SpriteKit Physics Contact logic as with other sprites.

Add a physics contact category bit mask for the blast nodes. 
When an event occurs that should create the blast, call a method that creates a blast node at the point of the event. 
Set the blast node position to the point. 
Add any actions to the blast node. 
Add the blast node to the scene. 
Its actions will run. 
In the physics contact delegate method, didBeginContact: you test for for contact with any nodes of categories that should react to contacting the blast node. 
If contact is made, basic thing is to tell the contacted node to removeFromeParent. 
Once you have that working, you can get fancy.

Your blast node should probably get a physics body of a circle based on a CGPath.

You should probably experiment with actions that scale it up and down. 
You can get more sophisticated by adding actions that provide animation, sound etc to the destruction of the other nodes, prior to removing them. 
If they are custom subclasses, it's a good time for a protocol that defines the method name to be blown up and removed. Then have each class implement that. 
Sounds like work but keeps your game logic code clean.

This overall process is going to be common and one you will get familiar with.

Comment: I got the concept of how do this, but im still having a bit of trouble turning into actual code. My whole project is uploaded to [https://github.com/HeisenbugXS/Brick-Breaker.git](https://github.com/HeisenbugXS/Brick-Breaker.git) If you could take a look at it and maybe give me some pointers on how to accomplish this with code, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I won't be at a computer before Thursday

Comment: Well just on how to turn this concept into actual code. I'm still pretty new to SpriteKit so I'm just having alittle trouble with it. Like would the blast sprite node be something thats transparent, like a mask or something? I was thinking i would use a SKEmitter node for the blast effect. I was checking Apples Doc's for creating a CGPath but its still abit confusing. And then also checking for contact between the blast and the bricks, since I have bricks that go in 5 rows with 8 columns, but i only want 2 in every direction to explode from the center of the blast.

Comment: I can look at the code in a few days. Until then, focus on the contact detection and response first. If you can achieve that step, everything else is decoration.